# Draw a line in the center of an A4 sheet iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to drawn an line in middle of page, but my code generate a line in footer of PDF

```
    public void GeneratePdf()
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 50, 50);
        var output = new FileStream("doctest.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        document.Open();

        document.NewPage();
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
        contentByte.SetLineWidth(1);
        contentByte.MoveTo(0, 14);
        contentByte.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width, 0);
        contentByte.Stroke();

        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

How to make to drawn the line in middle of page ?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle"? A horizontal line dividing top and bottom equally? A vertical line dividing left and right equally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to take in consideration here:

1. If you want to draw a line crossing the page, you need to put the same height in both the begin and the end; here you're starting the line in `14` and drawing it to `0`.
2. `iTextSharp` measures things in *user units*. A user unit corresponds with a point. There are 72 points in one inch, so if you want to put your line at the 14th inch, you should specify `14 * 72`
3. The position of the writer is from bottom to top; that's why when setting `14` as the start of the line draws it at the bottom.

With this in mind: if you want to draw your line right at the middle of the page, just use the page size:

```
contentByte.MoveTo(0, document.PageSize.Height / 2);
contentByte.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height / 2);
```

If you want to draw it at another position, measure in a real page at what position (in inches) you want to draw your line, substract it from the total size of the page and multiply it for 72. I.e. if you want to draw your line 5 inches from the top, considering A4 size is 8.3 * 11.7:

```
contentByte.MoveTo(0, (11.7f - 5f) * 72f);
contentByte.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width, (11.7f - 5f) * 72f);
```

Comment: Good answer (worth an up-vote), but I corrected one minor misconception.